# Search XML Column in SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, select

İ have an XML document to store against records in an Oracle Database.

The table CourseXML will contain:

```
Record_Number  int
XML_Type       int
XMLDoc         clob
...etc
```

İ would like to make a search in XMLDoc column by XML tags. The XML document has an XML Schema like this:

```
<root>
  <UnitID="2" Name="Jerry" SName="Potter"/>
  <UnitID="3" Name="Jim" SName="Carelyn"/>
</root>
```

İ want to make search in UnitID="2" and i only want Jerry's xml row. How I have to make a select statement query to get that xml row?

Comment: You might want to edit your posting to mention that you're using Oracle as your db server - might help.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to play with the nodes bit to get it exact.

```
SELECT
    y.item.value('@UnitID', 'int') AS UnitID,
    y.item.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)') AS [Name],
    y.item.value('@SName', 'varchar(100)') AS [SName]
FROM
    <table>
    CROSS APPLY
    XMLDoc.nodes('/root') AS y(item)
WHERE
    y.item.value('@UnitID', 'int') = 2
```

Edit: corrected code to use table, not xml local variable

Comment: @ThinkJet: tags were updated after this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/697256/revisions I answered for the information at the time

Comment: Ok, sorry for inconvience. I just missed comment for question at top of the page.

Comment: @ThinkJet: no problems, happens often :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have plenty of ways of getting it. "gbn" showed one way - two other are here.

If you want the whole "row" (I assumed you'll put these things into a  tag), try this:

```
select
    xmldoc.query('//node[@UnitID="2"]')
from
    xmltest
```

If you want just the "Name" attribute from the  tag, use this:

```
select
    xmldoc.value('(//node[@UnitID="2"]/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
from
    xmltest
```

If you need to access a whole bunch of attributes and/or subelements, use gbn's approach with the "CROSS APPLY xmldoc.nodes(....)".

Enjoy! XML Support in SQL Server 2005 is really quite extensive and useful!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CourseXML
WHERE XMLDoc = 'UnitID="2"'
```

Isn't that it?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Being the structure, and using Full Text Search.

```
<Root>
  <Tags>
    <TagName>Actividad</TagName>
    <Valor>Actividad 2</Valor>
  </Tags>
  <Tags>
    <TagName>Cliente</TagName>
    <Valor>Alpina</Valor>
  </Tags>
</Root>
```

```
 select 
     Filename
 from 
 Files
 where 
 CONTAINS(Tags,'Actividad')  and
 CONTAINS(Tags,'Cliente')  and
 Tags.exist('//Tags/Valor/text()[contains(., "Actividad 1")]')  = 1 and
 Tags.exist('//Tags/Valor/text()[contains(., "ADV")]')  = 1
```

I do not recommend using attributes on the XML, because full text search cannot be performed on attributes (no matter what the SQL 2008 R2 Docs say).

[Please Refer to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522491.aspx)